# PHP: Undefined variable error

Tags: php

I've the following `php` files in the same directory:

```
connection.php
index.php
lib.php
```

Relevant code of `connection.php`:

```
....
....
$client = 4; //something that I've defined here
....
....
```

Relevant code of `index.php`

```
require_once('connection.php');
require_once('lib.php');
....
function_search(); //function of lib.php
....
....
```

Relevant code of `lib.php`

```
class function_my_exception extends function_your_exception {

    function __construct($hint, $debuginfo=null) {
        parent::__construct($hint, 'debug', '', $hint, $debuginfo);
    }

}
function function_search(){
....
....
if ($client !=4 )
   //Do something 
}
```

When I run `index.php`, I keep getting the error `Undefined variable $client" in line xxx of lib.php`

Comment: if ($client !=4 ) --> what is in $client when this code runs? var dump it

Comment: `$client=4` as I've defined in `connection.php` file. When I merge the 3 files into one, they successfully run.

Comment: that's why I am asking you to var dump it, these are different scopes for that variable isn't it

Comment: Is `$client` a global variable and you are calling it inside a function?

Comment: See what you made me do! [Reference: What is variable scope and which variables are accessible from where?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-and-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because inside the function `function_search()`

`$client` is not available!

You can either pass it in as an argument to the function

```
function function_search($client)
{
...
}
```

And when you call the function you pass $client in

```
function_search($client);
```

Or you can use the `global` keyword to make it available within the function

Update: This global method should be avoided, because it's possible that somewhere in the code `$client` gets changed, and causes strange behavior or even errors within your script, it is generally better to pass the arguement to the function as you have more control of the variable.

```
function function_search()
{
    global $client;
...
}
```

Comment: yep pretty much same thing I was trying to get him to see in comments

Comment: :) I would make some joke about that being outside the scope of the question, but I can't be bothered lol!

Comment: Just a small note... it is better to pass $client into the `function($client)` rather than global, as it might get changed in some other places! In order to keep old function working, make it `function function_search($client=false)`

Comment: It's 3 am so if this question sounds stupid ignore it. But function function_search($client=false) would make $client a local variable for function_search without modifying the global one?

Comment: @wazy, `function function_search($client = false)` does indeed create a local $client variable for the function and leaves the other one unchanged, it also initializes it with a false value so that if you called `function_search();` the $client argument would be `false`, if you called `function_search(4);` the $client variable would be 4

Comment: If I called function_search(); then afterwards the global $client variable is set to false?

Comment: @wazy, No! just the $client local to the function, the other "global" $client will remain the same.

Comment: Yea that makes sense, I misread your previous comment and thus asked the followup question. Can't get the brain working anymore this early in the morning. Thanks for the response that clarified it a bit.

Comment: It would prbably be better if in the definition another name was used to avoid the confusion :) `function function_search($client_id){..}`

Answer (score 0):

Edit your lib.php to this:

```
class function_my_exception extends function_your_exception {

    function __construct($hint, $debuginfo=null) {
        parent::__construct($hint, 'debug', '', $hint, $debuginfo);
    }
// delete it here

    function function_search(){
    ....
    ....
    if ($client !=4 )
       //Do something 
    }

} // add it here
```

Note that you had a closing `}` just after the function __construct. it has to be at the end of those functions.